# How do I find $r$ in $2/64 = r^5$?

Tags: algebra-precalculus

I've never did an equation like this before, so I'm not sure how to remove the $r^5$. Self-explanatory title, any help is much appreciated.

$$2/64 = r^5$$

Comment: $64=2^6$, so $2/64=2^{-5}$.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

If $r\in\mathbb R,$ then

$$r^5=\frac{2}{64}\Rightarrow r^5=\left(\frac{1}{2}\right)^5\Rightarrow r=\frac{1}{2}.$$

If $r\in\mathbb C,$ then
$$r=\frac 12e^{2m\pi i/5}\ \ (m=0,1,2,3,4).$$

Comment: The $(-1)^{3/5}$ and related notation is quite unorthodox.

Comment: Yes, I agree with you:)

Comment: The answer isn't correct as written. You want $e^{2\pi n i/5}$ as $n$ varies. What you've written is that $i$ is an integer, not the square root of negative one.

Comment: @Mike: You are right! Thanks.

Answer (score -2):

$r^5=2/64$

then if take put both sides to the power of 1/5 or 0.2

$(r^5)^.2=(2/64)^.2$

then the exponent of $r$ becomes $1$ because the reciprocal of $5$ is $1/5$

$r^1=(2/64)^.2$

plug that in to a calculator and you are good to go

$r=0.5$ or $1/2$

don't forget to click the check mark